# Zorder of windows on dual monitors

Tags: windows, z-order, multiple-monitors

The z-order of a window indicates the window's position in a stack of overlapping windows. 
If you work with dual monitors, does each monitor have it's own z-order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Having separate Z-orders per monitor would make it difficult to get reasonable results when moving windows between monitors, or when windows overlapped multiple monitors. There is a single desktop-wide Z-order.

Comment: Is it possible to get the z-order of windows with visual c++?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's possible that a window may exist on both monitors simultaneously, so the z-order is for the entire desktop.